# how to make all columns visible in mobile of KTDatatable

Tags: datatable

I am using KTDatatable. it works like a charm in desktop view. but when I view the table on the mobile screen, only first two-column is being shown. Code:

```
<div class="kt-datatable"></div>

<script>
function listing(){
    $('.kt-datatable').KTDatatable({
        translate: {
            records: {
                processing: '{{"Please wait"|__}}...',
                noRecords: '{{"No records found"|__}}'
            },
            toolbar: {
                pagination: {
                    items: {
                        default: {
                            first: '{{"First"|__}}',
                            prev: '{{"Previous"|__}}',
                            next: '{{"Next"|__}}',
                            last: '{{"Last"|__}}',
                            more: '{{"More pages"|__}}',
                            input: '{{"Page number"|__}}',
                            select: '{{"Select page size"|__}}'
                        },

                        info: "{{"Displaying"|__}} {{ '{{' }}start{{ '}}' }} - {{ '{{' }}end{{ '}}' }} {{"of"|__}} {{total}} {{"records"|__}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // layout definition
        layout: {
            scroll: false, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
            footer: false, // display/hide footer
        },

        // column sorting
        sortable: true,

        pagination: true,

        search: {
            input: $('#generalSearch'),
            delay: 400,
        },
        data: {
            type: 'remote',
            source: {
                read: {
                    url: '{{url("api/dashboardpayments")}}'  
                },
            },
            pageSize: 10, // display 20 records per page
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true,
        },
        // columns definition
        columns: [
            {
                field: "id",
                title: "{{'#'|__}}",
                sortable: true,
                width: 100
            },
            {
                field: "amount",
                title: "{{'Amount'|__}}",
                sortable: false,
                width: 'auto',
            },
            {
                field: "trxId",
                title: "{{'trxId'|__}}",
                sortable: false,
                width: 'auto'
            },
            {
                field: "for",
                title: "{{'Service'|__}}",
                sortable: false,
                width: 'auto'
            },
            {
                field: "created_at_date",
                title: "{{'Date'|__}}",
                sortable: false,
                width: 'auto',
            },
            {
                    field: "Actions",
                    width: 100,
                    title: "{{'Actions'|__}}",
                    sortable: false,
                    overflow: 'visible',
                    template: function (data) {
                        var output = '' +
                        '<div class="btn-group btn-group">'+
                            '<a href="javascript:;" data-id='+data.id+' class="btn btn-brand btn-sm btn-icon confirmPayment" data-skin="dark" data-toggle="kt-tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{"OK"|__}}"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>';

                        '</div>';

                        return output;
                    },
                }     
        ]
    });
    $('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="kt-tooltip"]'});

}

</script>
```

I am trying a lot of possible ways of custom CSS. But no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put autoHide:false in a column definition. i.e:

```
columns: [
            {
                field: "id",
                title: "{{'#'|__}}",
                sortable: true,
                width: 100,
                autoHide: false
            }
         ]
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this work you can add the following:

```
rows: {
  autoHide: false
},
```

AND

```
// layout definition
   layout: {
   scroll: true, // enable/disable datatable scroll both horizontal and vertical when needed.
   footer: false, // display/hide footer
   header: true,
},
```